# thrust iterator mix usage

Tags: cuda, thrust

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/execution_policy.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
struct text_functor {
    text_functor() {}
    __host__ __device__ int operator()(const char t) const {
        if (t == '\n') return 0;
        return 1;
    }
};

void CountPosition1(const char *text, int *pos, int text_size)
{
    thrust::transform(text, text + text_size, pos, text_functor());
}
int main() {
    char s[4] = {'a', 'a', '\n', 'a'};
    int r[4] = {0};
    int *k;
    cudaMalloc((void**) &k, sizeof(int) * 4);
    CountPosition1(s, k, 4);
}
```

In thrust::transform, I mix host iterator s and device iterator k. This results in segmentation fault. If I change argument k to r in `CountPosition1` the program will be correct.
Should all iterator in a thrust function be from same source(both host or both device)? Or is there something wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, either all iterators should be from host containers, or all iterators should be from device containers.

Upon algorithm dispatch, [thrust will dispatch either the host path or the device path](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide).  All iterators should be consistent with the dispatch method.

Comment: But even as I apply all raw pointers to "text" and "pos", it still encounter segment fault. Can transform accept raw pointer as its arguments? Is it better to use device_pointer_cast?

Comment: not raw **device** pointers.  read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25242790/simple-sorting-using-thrust-not-working).  You should probably also read the entire thrust quick start guide that I linked in my answer.

Comment: message `0x0000000000403acd in thrust::detail::unary_transform_functor<text_functor>::operator()<thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<char const&, int&, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type> > (this=0x7fffffffe6ef, t=...) at /usr/local/cuda/bin/..//include/thrust/detail/internal_functional.h:322
322         thrust::get<1>(t) = f(thrust::get<0>(t));
`